# Any subset of X(discrete metric) is open.

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying topology.
I wonder that 'Any subset of X(discrete metric) is open'
Is it true? if it is false, please give me counter example.

Comment: Singleton sets are open in a discrete topology. Any set is a union of singleton sets.

Comment: If the discrete metric is $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ (and $=0$ otherwise), then it is true. Every singleton is open and any subset is a union of singletons.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you take a point $x \in U \subset X$ and consider $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ where $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$?