# Prove a fact involving discrete spaces

Tags: real-analysis

If $X$ is discrete, I want to prove that then $(\mathcal C_X,d_H)$ is discrete, where $$C_X=\{\text{non empty compact subsets of X}\}$$ and

$$d_H(A, B) = \inf\{ \epsilon > 0: A \subset U_{\epsilon}(B),\ \ B\subset U_\epsilon(A)\}.$$

So what I argued so far was that since the only compact sets of a discrete space $X$ are the singletons $\{x\}$,the set $C_X$ consists of those singletons, so we have that $C_X$ is discrete too.

My question is Am I right? or How can I fix the prolems of my proof?

Thanks a lot in advance.

NOTE: $$U_{\epsilon}(A)=\{x\in X: d(x,A)<\epsilon\}$$

Comment: Are you sure about your description of compact subsets of $X$?

Comment: only compact sets of a discrete space $X $are the singletons $\{x\}$ is not correct. all finite sets are compact

Comment: Ok :) that was the part I wasn't sure, so How can I fix it?

Comment: you can edit it.  what is $U_{\epsilon}(B)$?

Comment: Let me post the definition :) .

Comment: Ready: $$U_{\epsilon}(A)=\{x\in X: d(x,A)<\epsilon\}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious if $A\neq B$ then $d(A,B)=1$ and if $A=B$ then $d(A,B)=0$

Comment: right :) so...?

Comment: so every singleton is open,  thus $(\mathcal C_X,d_H)$ is discrete.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in this please? Thanks.

Comment: well, to prove that a set is discrete does it suffices to prove that the singleton is open?

Comment: yes. you are right.

Comment: so How do you prove that with your answer? Thnks

Comment: So then, Can you provide an answer with all the details please?  :) Thnks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721047/any-subset-of-xdiscrete-metric-is-open

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248178/definition-of-open-ball-in-discrete-metric-space

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407666/topology-induced-by-discrete-metrics-and-topology-induced-by-singleton

Comment: Let me check them, and if I have questions, Can I let you know?

Comment: Well, I really, don't get your answer, becuase I know that singletons are closed in any metric space, but now you wrote the discrete metric for sets, (that part I think is find since $C_X$ is formed by sets) , so I don't understand the sequence, or logic that this has , that is why I told that if you can provide a more structured answer with all the details of the proof, thanks :) in advance